# error when using https with flutter http.dart package

Tags: http, flutter

i am usin http.dart package to make http post for login, everything is work good when my restful api in localhost and with (http protocol), but when upload my backend api to shared host with (https protocol):

```
I/flutter (12071): HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error:
I/flutter (12071):      CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate(handshake.cc:363))
```

this is my code for http request:

```
final res = await http
    .post(Uri.encodeFull(url),
     body: {"email": _user.text, "password": _pass.text},
     headers: {'Accept' : 'application/json'});
```

this is all debug message:

```
E/flutter (12071): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(184)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (12071): HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error:
E/flutter (12071):      CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate(handshake.cc:363))
E/flutter (12071): #0      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:33:23)
E/flutter (12071): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12071): #1      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:169:38)
E/flutter (12071): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12071): #2      BaseClient.post (package:http/src/base_client.dart:54:7)
E/flutter (12071): #3      post.<anonymous closure> (package:http/http.dart:70:16)
E/flutter (12071): #4      _withClient (package:http/http.dart:166:20)
E/flutter (12071): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12071): #5      post (package:http/http.dart:69:5)
E/flutter (12071): #6      LoginState._login (package:mis/auth/login.dart:41:23)
E/flutter (12071): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12071): #7      LoginState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:mis/auth/login.dart:216:31)
E/flutter (12071): #8      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:507:14)
E/flutter (12071): #9      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:562:30)
E/flutter (12071): #10     GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:102:24)
E/flutter (12071): #11     TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:242:9)
E/flutter (12071): #12     TapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:204:7)
E/flutter (12071): #13     GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:156:27)
E/flutter (12071): #14     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:184:20)
E/flutter (12071): #15     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:158:22)
E/flutter (12071): #16     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:138:7)
E/flutter (12071): #17     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:101:7)
E/flutter (12071): #18     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:85:7)
E/flutter (12071): #19     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:168:13)
E/flutter (12071): #20     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:122:5)
```

Comment: Related issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27883

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54728717/error-when-using-https-with-flutter-http-dart-package#new-answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54551198/how-to-solve-socketexception-failed-host-lookup-www-xyz-com-os-error-no-ad/55548864#55548864

Answer (score 3):

According to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27883

Just add

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

in your app's **android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml**

Answer (score 1):

add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`
in your app's **android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml** file

> and make sure your device has internet connection.