# How to resolve - SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'server.com' (OS Error: nodename nor servname provided, or not known, errno = 8)

Tags: flutter, http, web-services, https, socketexception

I am pretty new to flutter development. I am getting the following error on connecting to the server:

> SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'server.com' (OS Error: nodename nor servname provided, or not known, errno = 8)

I already referred the below link, but this was of no help for me

[How to solve SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'www.xyz.com' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54551198/how-to-solve-socketexception-failed-host-lookup-www-xyz-com-os-error-no-ad)

Currently I am testing my application on iOS simulator. Below are the versions I am using,

- Http version - http: ^0.12.2
- Flutter version - 1.22.4(Stable version)

The server is connecting when I am using mobile hotspot with my company's VPN enabled. But, I get this error when I switch to the company LAN.

All the APIs are working fine in postman when connected to LAN. I am using Android Studio. Is there any specific configuration to be made in flutter? Please let me know...

Comment: can you access 'server.com' from browser while you are on company LAN?

Comment: Yes I can access it from the browser. Also, the apis are working in postman when I am connected to LAN. The only issue is with flutter. Not sure why this is not working only in flutter. I am using Android Studio.

Answer (score -2):

Internet is off or signal is not strong. Check your LAN connection.

Comment: This is not an answer, it should be a comment.