# unhandled Exception: SocketException: Failed host lookup: URL (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7)

Tags: flutter, http, dart, flutter-http

##### EDIT: Question is now Solved

---

I tried the solution over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54551198/how-to-solve-socketexception-failed-host-lookup-www-xyz-com-os-error-no-ad) but it didn't work out for me.

**cases**

1. I have provided internet permissions
2. I am running it on the actual device
3. there is an active internet connection on my device

basically, I built an API in python and deployed it on `vercel`. now I am trying to fetch details from my API using flutter. the link is `https://dailyhunt.vandit.cf/dailyhunt?category=technology`

it works fine on `web` but doesn't work on an actual device

my code is too long and is separated in multiple files so i can provide with this:

```dart
import 'package:news_app/models/article_model.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:news_app/constants.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class News {
  List<ArticleModel> news = [];

  Future getNews() async {
    http.Client client = http.Client();
    http.Response response = await client.get(Uri.parse(kDailyhuntEndpoint));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);

      if (jsonData['success'] == true) {
        jsonData['data'].forEach((element) {
          if (element['imageUrl'] != "" && element['content'] != "") {
            List<String> raw = element['PublishedTime'].split(" ");
            String date = raw[0];
            String time = raw[1];
            ArticleModel articleModel = ArticleModel(
              publishedDate: date,
              publishedTime: time,
              image: element['imageUrl'].toString(),
              content: element['content'].toString(),
              fullArticle: element['publisherStory'].toString(),
              views: element['viewCount'].toString(),
              title: element['title'].toString(),
            );
            news.add(articleModel);
          }
        });
      } else {
        print('ERROR');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i am also facing the same problem!

Comment: Are you testing on emulator?

Comment: @OMiShah on actual device

Answer (score 0):

It is giving response. I have tested it on real device it is working fine

```
    Future getNews() async {
    http.Response response = await http
        .get("https://dailyhunt.vandit.cf/dailyhunt?category=technology");

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
      print(jsonData);

      if (jsonData['success'] == true) {}
    } else {
      print('ERROR');
    }
  }
```

Comment: it is giving a response to me too if I print it but when I run the app it is showing the above error

Comment: run the app ? like perform some task ? i cannot clearly understand.

Comment: "https://dailyhunt.vandit.cf/dailyhunt?category=technology " this url not working now

Comment: my problem is solved, also the API is running fine IDK id it was down at the time of your comment