# How to solve SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'localhost' errno = 11004

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I just started learning flutter and then during my first run & debug for unit test, i got an error SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'localhost' (OS Error: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found. , errno = 11004) when running in a web browser.

Comment: Have you tried this? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54551198/how-to-solve-socketexception-failed-host-lookup-www-xyz-com-os-error-no-ad

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.